# Cordova iOS Build Archive Succeeds, but Export fails without error on XCode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, xcode9

I have a build process set-up in Visual Studio Team Services, doing a remote build to a Mac. The build uses the Cordova Build extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.cordova-extension) and it is failing after installing XCode 9 on the build computer.

The build was running fine, but we ran into a development issue with iOS 11. In order to debug, we had to install XCode 9.0. Now the remote build no longer works. Everything works fine through the Archive process, but then it fails without an error. The output is:

`
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **

** EXPORT FAILED **

Removing Xcconfig update hook
`

Some facts:

I have updated to the last stable build of cordova-ios (4.4.0).
I am using Cordova 6.5.0.
I have no problem doing the build itself on the machine or through remotebuild.
I have no problem building this project in XCode itself. 
I can export the project from XCode with no problem.

When I first built the project, I got the following error between the Archive and Export steps

`xcodebuild[57828:11533606] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: : Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed., IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(

"Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 \"\"Field Nimble.app\" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=\"Field Nimble.app\" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the \"provisioningProfiles\" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}"
2017-09-20T01:20:36.4336250Z )}`

After some research, I tried Darryl Pogue's xcode8.js hook (https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html). This removed the error, the build still fails.

Comment: I have the same issue when building my app. Started to happen after xcode9 update
`cordova cli: 7.0.1`

Comment: There is a similar issue on the fastlane repo. https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/10315

Comment: This has been answered in a different post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344443/after-upgrading-to-xcode-9-cordova-app-wont-build-error-70-requires-provisio/46370957#46370957

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After upgrading to xcode 9, cordova app won't build, error 70, requires provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344443/after-upgrading-to-xcode-9-cordova-app-wont-build-error-70-requires-provisio)